# Having trouble repairing window xp that is dual-booted with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I had been successfully using Windows XP dual-booted with Ubuntu, for over 2 years. 
Then, out of the blue, something happened to the Windows boot file that made it impossible for me to get into Windows. A message appeared that said something to the effect that the
boot file may be corrupted...

I've tried to use an XP disc to apply the Recovery mode, or even
a re-install if it came to that, but the disc informs me that no
Windows program can be detected. And I'm apparently not allowed to
proceed further.

My Ubuntu partition works fine, as always.

Any suggestions for fixing this thing would be enormously appreciated!

Comment: upload gparted screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot from your CD using EFI-shell. You can choose this option in the bios settings (stands right next to the boot-override-option). That worked for me.

Else use  [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and post the result here.